# Database helper class

Tags: android

Can you tell me why we are using Database Helper class in Android? What is the function of this class?

Comment: I am not using a Database Helper class. What do you refer to? (and: what If I was not a sir, but a lady?)

Answer (score 0):

Because it...helps?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html :

> A helper class to manage database
>   creation and version management.

I personally find it's really handy and it makes the SQLite DB handling in my application very easy. I was surprised how simple it is to implement DB handling.

I also enjoy the fact that I just use the instance of my helper class and `getWriteableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` depending on what I need and it just works.